# oracle join depth while updating table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a question regarding Oracle.

I know that Oracle only support the use of aliases to the first subquery level. This poses a problem when I want to group more than one time while updating a table.

Example: I have some server groups and a database containing information about them. I have one table that contains information about the groups and one table where I store with timestamp (to be exact: I used date actually) the workload of specific servers within the groups.

Now I have for performance issues a denormalized field in the server table containing the highest workload the group had within one day.

What I would like to do is something like

```
update server_group 
    set last_day_workload=avg(workload1)
    from (select max(workload) workload1
        from server_performance
        where server_performance.server_group_ID_fk=server_group.ID
            and time>sysdate-1
        group by server_performance.server_group_ID_fk)
```

While ID is the primary key of server_group and server_group_ID_fk a foreign key reference from the server_performance table. The solution I am using so far is writing the first join into a temporary table and update from that temporary table in the next statement. Is there a better way to do this?

In this problem it isn`t such a problem yet, but if the amount of data increase using a temporary table cost not only some time, but also a notable amount of RAM.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would work out the results that I wanted in a select statement, and then use [a MERGE statement](http://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement.php) to do the necessary update.

Comment: Thank you for that comment. The problem I have is that I first materialize the solution and join it afterwards with a condition again over the big table (just like I'm doing now with my temporary table). Even though it's an exact join this takes some time to perform it (usually it's ok, because index for non-sematic PKs are small enough to stay buffered). If the PK index would be to big to stay buffered, it would be totally crazy.

Comment: What would you do in case you want to update this field not only one time a day, but also with a trigger when another column currently_monitored changes? It would be a total waste to calculate the whole table to merge just a single line into the actual table.

Comment: Your original example isn't particularly clear, though, so it's difficult to advise you on the best course of action. Perhaps if you were to update your question with create table scripts (including constraints and indexes) of the tables you're working with and sample data (as insert statements), along with the expected output, we could help you better.

Comment: The merge is done based on whatever data is to be updated - if you're only updating a handful of rows, then you're only merging a handful of rows, if that makes sense?
Is the update to your currently_monitored column done directly from the front end (ie. non-db) code, or is it done via a stored procedure? If the latter, I'd do the logic in the stored proc, rather than faff around with a trigger.

Comment: Thank you, that helps. Even though it is kinda similar to the way like I used before, just the code is a little bit more clear and the specific memory parts within the database RAM changes. But with my specific configuration it seems to be faster anyways. Thank you!